# Поворот двумерного примитива во время движения в OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Здравствуйте, как реализовать поворот двумерного примитива во время движения в OpenGL?
Управляется клавиатурой.

Пока делаю так:

```
glTranslatef( ); // двигаем примитив
glRotatef(угол поворота, 0, 0, 1); // поворот
glTranslatef( ); /*если во время движения нажали "направо", сдвигаем примитив налево, относительно оси вращения*/
Примитив(x, y);
```

Проблема, естественно, в том, что при повороте направо, я сдвигаю примитив, и его позиция меняется, как это исправить? Думаю до вращения примитива нужно его еще раз сместить, но что написать в координатах?

```
glTranslatef(?, ?, ?); // если нажали "направо", сдвигаем примитив
```

P.S. Я новичок и буду рад любым советам, книжкам, ссылкам, Спасибо (:

UPD. Спасибо, вопрос решен.

Comment: Может сначала сделать поворот, а потом уже смещение в нужное положение?

    glRotatef(угол поворота, 0, 0, 1); // поворот
    glTranslatef( ); // двигаем примитив (бывшая первая строка)
    Примитив(x, y);

Comment: Наверно вы меня не правильно поняли, вначале я двигаю примитив по экрану, нажатием клавиши вперед. Нажатием на клавиши влево или вправо, во время движения, фигура должна описывать дугу в том или ином направлении.

Comment: И правда неправильно понял:) Возможно я бы смог помочь, если бы был кусок компилируемого кода. А так может кто-нибудь ответит, кто получше меня шарит в OpenGL:)

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен, уменьшив ближнюю плоскость отсечения, анализировать стало проще, смещая примитив туда-сюда-таки получилось (: